# How to go around the "failed: Connection refused" error?

Tags: ftp, download, wget, https

I need to download all the files in some URL which points to a folder that has a couple thousand files of approximately 10kB each. I've tried using `-w 1` to avoid overwhelming the server, but it still created the error and stopped downloading midway due to refused connection.

Now `wget` won't even work and I don't know how to make it continue from where it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is returning `Connection refused` after you sent too many requests, this is an issue that is wholly out of your control. Your IP address has likely been temporarily blacklisted by an automated system, something you cannot change.

Attempting to bypass the temporary ban by using VPNs and such is going against the wishes of the webmaster–it is unethical and perhaps even illegal.

You need to wait for the automated ban to be lifted.

Comment: Yikes! I didn't know that... thanks for your response... I do have a follow-up question though... Is there a way to pick up the download from the file I last downloaded and go on from there? Because every time I throw the command there, it just restarts from the top...

Comment: Yes. To pick up a download from where it started with `wget`, use the `-c` flag as such: `wget -c -O [your_filename] [url]`. If my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted  and give me an upvote! :)

Comment: So if the last downloaded file was FILE135.jpg, I just do a "wget -c -0 FILE135.jpg https://mywebsite/data/" and it'll start from FILE135.jpg? Your answer was very helpful thank you!... I tried to upvote you, but it says that I don't have enough upvotes myself to be able to do it. It did say that my opinion was recorded though... Thanks a bunch!